# React lazy loading to a hash map

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

In order to dynamic import module, is the code working for lazy loading?

1. `xxx.ts`

```js
export default names.reduce(
  (map: Record<string, React.LazyExoticComponent<any>>, name) => {
    map[name] = React.lazy(() =>
      import('module').then((objects) => ({
        // warning
        // No index signature with a parameter of type string was found on type
        default: objects[name]
      }))
    )

    return map
  },
  {}
)
```

2. and use at other place, `other.tsx`

```js
import Modules from 'xxx'

<Suspense fallback="loading...">
  {React.createElement(Modules[name])}
</Suspense>
```

and how to clean that warning?

This seems to be working fine, but I don't know if it works with lazy loading.

Comment: What is the type of `objects`?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev `objects` is `typeof import('any module')`